# Using object instance as a key in React list

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have a list of objects which I want to render as a list using React.

React requires the special `key` attribute on the list element in order to track changes between DOM and virtual DOM.

My object doesn't have any special unique properties like `id`, in fact, two objects could even have the same properties, but the object itself is unique.

Is there a way to use object's reference as a key to render React list?

Otherwise, what workarounds could be suggested in this case?

---

Also, I'm receiving the list of items from a third party, so I can't just attach a random ID to each item, because it will make the React to re-render all items each time I receive updated data.

Comment: I'd suggest to generate random id. for example from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniqueId)

Comment: attach a counter to key?

Comment: It's common practice to attach a "dummy" id to your objects, or if the order of array elements will not change you can use the [index of the array as key as last resort](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: Generating a random ID each render is pointless, you should generate them at the time you create the objects/receive them from the server (or just do it on the server)

Comment: If I attach a generated dummy ID to each item when I receive them wouldn't it make React to re-render all the items when I receive updated data?

Comment: Yes, if you get all the data again and overwrite it with new dummy IDs, they will all re-render. You might be able to figure out which data is new and just add that, or there might be some real unique identifier attached to your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a unique ID (returned by the back-end, or you can't build a composite key on the front-end), then you can use the array index as key:

```
render() {
  return array.map((item, index) => <Item key={index} />)
}
```

Without having an unique ID, whatever approach you choose, if the order of the items is changed, then the list can get totally messed up.

It would be safe enough to use this approach if your case met the following 3 conditions, thanks to [this article](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318):

1. the list and items are static–they are not computed and do not change.
2. the items in the list have no ids.
3. the list is never reordered or filtered.

Comment: What if order of items would change?

Comment: I expanded the answer - when this approach is safe enough.

Answer (score 0):

> Using array's `index` as a `key` would be a disaster, because if array changes, the view will not be properly updated or will be updated partially in an unpredictable manner.

The only solution I've found is to generate the dummy IDs as suggested in the comments.

The idea is to implement the generator, which will create an ID for each item, but at the same time will remember previously generated IDs.

The [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) JavaScript class will allow us to store the mapping information between the item object reference and generated ID:

```js
export class IdGenerator {

  // Using WeakMap as index
  map = new WeakMap();

  // Internal counter
  lastId = 0;

  getItemId(item) {

    // Getting previously generated ID for the specified item
    let id = this.map.get(item);

    // If item is new, generating the ID and storing it for future use
    if (undefined === id) {
      id = ++(this.lastId);
      this.map.set(item, id);
    }

    // Returning ID to the caller in either case
    return id;

  }

}
```

Then it could be used to assign generated IDs to each item before rendering the list:

```js
class ListBox extends Component {

  // Instantiating the generator
  itemsIdGenerator = new IdGenerator();

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map(item => (
          <li key={this.itemsIdGenerator.getItemId(item)}>
            {item.title}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

}
```

Make sure to use different instance of the generator for each instance of the component though and create generator only once with the component.

Also, calling the generator for each item in component's render method could be sub-optimal. However, I didn't want to touch the original items or mutate them. If this is an issue, consider using various lifecycle methods provided by React to set IDs when props changes.